# ffmpeg command to convert mpeg2 with ac3 audio codec to audible H264/ ProResHQ?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I try to convert a mpeg2 video to mov with codec ac3 but when put ffmpeg -i 1.mpg 1.mov the audio don't convert.

¿Anyone know why?

Comment: So your source is MPEG-2 video and AC3 audio and you wish to convert to H264 video and AC3 audio in MOV?

Comment: Exactly, and then only convert the video, without audio...

Comment: Paste it at Pastebin.com and link it here.

Comment: You have exceeded the maximum file size of 512 kilobytes per paste. PRO users don't have this limit! :( Damn!

Comment: How big is the .MPG? Run the following command and paste its console output:  ffmpeg -i 1.mpg -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k -t 5 1.mov

Comment: the command It's running! the .mpg have 486 MB

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mpg -c:v libx264 -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k 1.mov
```

in order to convert to a MOV file containing H.264 video and AC3 audio. I've used 192kb/s as bitrate for the audio and the H.264 encoding will use the defaults of CRF 23 and preset 'medium'.

To convert only video, and strip out audio, use

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mpg -c:v libx264 -an 1.mov
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but still not convert the audio, the specs of source video are:  Vídeo: MPEG-1/2 Video (mpgv) 720x576 25fps Planar 4:2:0 YUV and Audio are: DVD LPCM Audio (lpcm) Stereo, 48000 Hz 16 bits.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The conversion is successful, but the video does not have audio. Don't show any error...

Comment: Try converting to AAC and see if it works: ffmpeg -i 1.mpg -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 192k 1.mov

Comment: It seems that does not convert the audio, because the video is converted properly and when try to audio audio ffmpeg returns: 0 kb, I don't know why...

Comment: Can you paste the complete console output into your question?